# How to show newly added attributes on pd.DataFrame object on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working with around 50 different df and adding names for those df.

so, am trying to figure out a way to display newly added attribute (in this case name)

for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]],columns=["a","b"])
df.name = "name of the table I want to display"

df.head()

>>>
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8

4 rows x 2 columns
Name: name of the table I want to display
```

as a default, I know that pd.DataFrame display the data and shape of the dataframe. However, I would like to know if there is way to automatically display those information?

Comment: You can always make a function which takes the DataFrame and returns the contents and the name as a string.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest storing the DataFrames in a dictionary: `{'df_name': pd.DataFrame()}`. Yes you *can* define an attribute like that, but you're really not meant to, and there are so many pitfalls that arise. For instance, any attributes you define that way do not persist across I/O operations, even if you choose a format like `.pkl` that is capable of serializing python objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what you assign, call `name` will return the df name

```
df.name
'name of the table I want to display'
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to your question i've checked attributes but even `df.info()` has no display name of dataframe. It would be nice to display it with `df.info()`. (Pandas version is 1.0.0)

You can use something like this:

```
def display_df(df, head=True):
    if head:
        print(df.head())
        print(f'Shape of DataFrame: {df.shape}')
        print(f'Name of DataFrame: {df.name}')
    else:
        print(df)
        print(f'Shape of DataFrame: {df.shape}')
        print(f'Name of DataFrame: {df.name}')

display_df(df)
```